# Eclipse - JPA EclipseLink Generating tables from entities

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, eclipselink

Hi i'm trying to generate db tables from entities in eclipse. but it does not show schema generation dialog as shown in this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/docs/3.2/user_guide/tasks007.htm). when i click "Generate table from  entities" it does nothing.

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="TestEclipsLink" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1234"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Entity class

```
package db.enitity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.TableGenerator;

@Entity
@TableGenerator(name="person")
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private String name;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in error log window ?

Comment: if everything seems ok, but not working.you may hit a bug, so check eclipse logs. http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F

Comment: Is there any output?  Try adding other EclipseLink properties to your persistence.xml such as Finest logging <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>.  Could it be that you pointed Eclipse at a different database then the one you are looking for tables in?